# MySQL SELECT doesn't work in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this MySQL query

```sql
SELECT 
    kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.nazev as odlisujici_nazev, 
    tolerovana, 
    zadana, 
    aktualni
FROM kompetence_odlisujici, kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories
WHERE kompetence_odlisujici.os_cislo_zamestnanec = ? 
AND tolerovana <> 0 
AND zadana <> 0 
AND aktualni <> 0 
AND year = ? 
AND IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.active = 1
AND kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.id = PR.kompetence_odlisujici.id_odlisujici_subcategory
```

and it works fine if I try it in MySQL Workbench but when I try to use it in my java code I get this error

```
SQLException :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE kompetence_odlisujici.os_cislo_zamestnanec = '123456' AND tolerovana <> 0 ' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT** java code

```
DataSourcePool dspService = sling.getService(DataSourcePool.class);
DataSource dsMySql = (DataSource) dspService.getDataSource("myConnection");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
if(dsMySql != null){
String sqlQuery = "SELECT kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.nazev as odlisujici_nazev, tolerovana, zadana, aktualni"+
                "FROM IPR.kompetence_odlisujici, kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories "+
                "WHERE IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.os_cislo_zamestnanec = ? AND tolerovana <> 0 AND zadana <> 0 AND aktualni <> 0 AND year = ? AND IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.active = 1"+
                "AND kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.id = IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.id_odlisujici_subcategory";
  Connection mySqlConnection = mySqlConnection = dsMySql.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = mySqlConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
  String workingUser = this.getWorkingUser();
  int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, workingUser);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, year);
  ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
  resultSet.last();
    int count = resultSet.getRow();
    resultSet.beforeFirst();
  /*
  parse result set here
  */
}
```

Comment: Please include your java code.

Comment: Do you have a space or newline character at the end of the `FROM ...` line, or in fact on every line?

Comment: seems to me either os_cislo_zamestnanec is a number and doesn't need the ticss

Comment: Some of your lines are missing spaces.  `"...aktualni" + "FROM..."` needs a space on one side or the other, as it currently combines to `aktualniFROM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.nazev as odlisujici_nazev, tolerovana, zadana, aktualni "+
                "FROM IPR.kompetence_odlisujici, kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories "+
                "WHERE IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.os_cislo_zamestnanec = ? AND tolerovana <> 0 AND zadana <> 0 AND aktualni <> 0 AND year = ? AND IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.active = 1 "+
                "AND kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.id = IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.id_odlisujici_subcategory";
```

No space between `aktualni` and `FROM`, and no space between `IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.active = 1` and `AND kompetence.kompetence_odlisujici_subcategories.id = IPR.kompetence_odlisujici.id_odlisujici_subcategory`.

Also my suggestion is that you make these queries as `private static final` in the class.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that there are spaces missing! Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. You're not the only one that had this issue :D